# how to create our own custom filter so that we get an access over there using directshow

Tags: winapi, audio, com, directshow

I have a question regarding Media Playback which is as below . 
Please solve my problem

"i have an audio stream which is successfully compressed by using direct show, now before entering it to the rendering filter 
i need to create my own custom filter so that i have full access over it , because by using existing filter i am not able to get access over the file."// This is my question

I have read about Direct show.The Microsoft Direct Show application programming interface (API) is a media-streaming architecture for Microsoft Windows. Using Direct Show, your applications can perform high-quality video and audio playback or capture.

The Direct Show headers, libraries, SDK tools, and samples are available in the Windows SDK.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 2):

Windows SDK also offers you samples. [Gargle Filter Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in `\Samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\gargle` is close to what you need: mid-point filter for audio with full control over streamed data.

```
//     Summary
//
// A simple, in-place transform, audio effect which modifies the data
// in the samples that pass through it.  The effect is an amplitude
// modulation with a synthesised secondary wave function.
// The secondary wave can be a triangular or square wave.  A properties
// sheet allows the shape and frequency of the secondary wave to be chosen.
//
// At low modulation frequencies it sounds like a tremolo, at higher
// modulation frequencies it sounds like a distortion, adding extra
// frequencies above and below the original unmodulated sound.
```